# _findnext64 crashed with access violation

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit

I am trying to get all the files with the specific wildcard extension such as "`right_*.jpg`" Somehow this code crashed on run time with "`access violation`". This is for x64 build.

```
int GetDir64(const char *dir, const char *str_wildcard, std::vector<std::string> &files)
    {
        char pathstr[500];
        struct  __finddata64_t  c_file;
        long hFile;
        sprintf(pathstr, "%s\\%s", dir, str_wildcard); 
        printf("GetDir(): %s\n", pathstr);

        if ((hFile = _findfirst64(pathstr, &c_file)) != -1L)
        {
            do
            {
                std::string fn_str = std::string(c_file.name);
                files.push_back(fn_str);
            } while (_findnext64(hFile, &c_file) == 0); // this is where the crash happened 
            _findclose(hFile);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the `_findfirst` functions are [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/findfirst-functions?view=vs-2017) as returning `intptr_t`.  If you have a 64-bit build, `intptr_t` is 64 bits wide.  You are storing the result in a long - which is only 32 bits wide, thus truncating the returned handle.

If you had written the code as:

```
       const auto hFile = _findfirst64(pathstr, &c_file);
       if (hFile != -1)
```

then this would not have been a problem.

(I would also construct pathstr as a `std::string` and use `.c_str()` to obtain the pointer.  I hate fixed sized arrays.)